# Issue on proper regex pattern format for links

Tags: javascript, regex

```
pattern_for_links = /
        (((((http|ftp|https):\/{2}|([0-9a-z_-]+\.)+)|)(([0-9a-z_-]+\.)+(com)(:[0-9]+)?
        ((\/([~0-9a-zA-Z\#\+\%@@\.\/_-]+))?(\?[0-9a-zA-Z\+\%@@\/&\[\];=_-]+)?)?))\b)
                    /gmi;
```

And I get this match (*JS*) which is fine and all matches correct:

```
http://www.yahoo.com 
yahoo.com/wordss
www.yahoo.com
```

But when I add `/` at the end, then `/` is not included (*`/` not matched*).

```
http://www.yahoo.com/
yahoo.com/wordss/
www.yahoo.com/
```

How can I also include `/` at the end, using `pattern_for_links`?

**EDIT**

Solution: I added `\b\/?` instead of only `\b`, and now `/` also matched and included.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/(https?:\/\/(www\.)?)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)/gmi
```

Taken from [Regex for URL: SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url), with slight modification to catch both `http/https` prefixed `URLs`, and `URLs` without them.

Also, for a quick and easy RegEx making (and learning), see [RegExr.com](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: /(https?:\/\/(www\.)?)?[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{2,256}\.[a-z]{2,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~#?&\/=]*)/gmi; it's \/=]*) not //=]*)

Comment: @yudongshen Thanks! Edited. :)